# Validation errors when saving

Tags: breeze

When saving using `SaveChanges()` using Breeze, I get an error when doing a simple update if I have required fields.

E.g.

I have a table of users with a `Name`, and `Email` fields where the `Email` field is not required.

I can display the list of user names (but do not want to display the emails).

The display works, but save never gets called - I get a validation error in JavaScript:

> Not saved due to validation error: 'email' is required

But surely this should be just generating a simple update on the field I have changed and should not be doing anything with email.

Oddly, I don't get an error if I just alter the 1st item in the list.

Any ideas?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: save">Save</a>
<ul data-bind="foreach: modules">
<li >
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsRunning" />
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: ModuleName, css: { done: IsRunning }" />
    </form>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

and the viewmodel save part is below:

```
function saveChanges() {
    if (manager.hasChanges()) {
        manager.saveChanges()
            .then(saveSucceeded)
            .fail(saveFailed);
    } else {
        logger.info("Nothing to save");
    };
}
function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
    logger.success("# of Modules saved = " + saveResult.entities.length);
    logger.log(saveResult);
}

function saveFailed(error) {
    var reason = error.message;
    var detail = error.detail;

    if (reason === "Validation error") {
        handleSaveValidationError(error);
        return;
    }
    if (detail && detail.ExceptionType.indexOf('OptimisticConcurrencyException') !== -1) {
        // Concurrency error 
        reason =
            "Another user, perhaps the server, may have deleted one or all of the todos.";
        manager.rejectChanges(); // DEMO ONLY: discard all pending changes
    }

    logger.error(error,
        "Failed to save changes. " + reason +
        " You may have to restart the app.");
};
function handleSaveValidationError(error) {
    var message = "Not saved due to validation error";
    try { // fish out the first error
        var firstErr = error.entitiesWithErrors[0].entityAspect.getValidationErrors()[0];
        message += ": " + firstErr.errorMessage;
    } catch (e) { /* eat it for now */ } 
    logger.error(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hm... you say that email is not required but the metadata thinks that it is.  Can you confirm this by looking at the metadata for this property?  The code will look something like this.

```
var userType = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("User");
var emailProp = userType.getProperty("email");
var isRequired = !emailProp.isNullable;
```

If the metadata thinks the field is required then it was probably set to this on the server. So take a look at your EF model and check that the [Required] attribute hasn't been added to this property.  Also, check if this field is nonnullable is the database.

One other item to note, by default breeze will try to validate the ***entire*** entity on the server before any save, **even those fields that were not touched**, even though only the modified fields will actually get updated. This is by design.

However, you can suppress this behavior by setting the entityManager's 'validationOptions' like so:

```
var vo = new breeze.ValidationOptions({ 
    validateOnSave: false,
    validateOnQuery: false, // not needed here but shown for completeness
    validateOnAttach: true  // not needed here but shown for completeness
});
myEntityManager.setProperties({ validationOptions: vo });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry - my question was not clear. Email is required by the DB but not shown or used in the application. I understand now that the validation is getting in the way so I solved (for now) by switching off the validation. BUT what is odd is that email field does have a value - but it is not shown to the user so should cause a validation error - should it ?

Comment: breeze doesn't actually know what you render in the UI, it only knows about the model.  If the property is in the metadata and is required then, by default, it will be validated. The idea is that just because it was on the db does not mean that it's valid. However, if you don't need the property, you can exclude it from the model.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Rereading your comment, are you saying that the validation is actually incorrect, that it is reporting a required validation error even though it contains data, or is it some other error being reported by the validation?